# How To Set UIColor Value To CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor

Tags: iphone, ipad

How to set `UIColor` value into `CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor`

// This is red color which i set to the `CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor`
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(contextRef, 1, 0, 0,1.00f);

Now i do have UIColor which has RGB value i need to set this value to `CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor`.

Any one suggest me how to set `UIColor` value's `CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
CGFloat red, green, blue, alpha;
[color getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(contextRef, red, green, blue, alpha);
```

Answer (score 14):

Alternative:

```
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]);

// or
[[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

For the lazy :

```
let myUIColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
var r:CGFloat, g:CGFloat, b:CGFloat, a:CGFloat = 0
myUIColor.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(c, r, g, b, a)

// or 
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(myUIColor.CGColor);
```

#SwiftStyle

Comment: You don't need to set the context when using `CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(myUIColor.CGColor)`?

Answer (score 0):

**In swift 3.0**

```
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
context!.setStrokeColor(red: 1,green: 1,blue: 1,alpha: 1)
```

Or you can ser color as below

```
context!.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)//or any UIColor
```